# What's the most convenient way to globally set 2 different form themes for app back-end and front-end

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So, theming a form in Symfony2 is easy. You create a custom theme file and you add it to your config.yml file to load it. Done.

However, I have 2 different form themes. One for the front-end of the application and one for the back-end of the application.

I went through the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) but couldn't find a good and easy way to do this.

When I add the theme to the config.yml file, I have the same theme in both front-end and back-end. I could also include the form within each view like this

```
{% form_theme form 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
```

However, that means I have to do it within each view.

Is there somehow a way to create a separate config file for front-end and back-end? Can I somehow indicate in the base template file which form theme should be used?

Anything else I could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Symfony2 default directory structure, i.e. you have a single kernel for both the frontend and the backend, you can only (as you mentioned) either set the form theme in each template, or use the same template application-wide by setting it in the `config.yml` file.

The alternative solution you mentioned, that is creating two base templates, each one setting a "global" `form_theme` tag would theoretically work. Create a base `front-end.html.twig` template for all your frontend pages with the following tag:

```
{% form_theme form 'form-front-end.html.twig' %}
```

That would work, but you would be forced to have a `form` variable in each inherited template. You would also not be able to set the theme to multiple forms in the same page.

You could improve the solution by checking if the form variable is defined before styling it:

```
{% if form is defined %}
  {% form_theme form 'form-front-end.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

or even better, if you want to be able to passing multiple form to the same template, you could do it by using a `forms` array:

```
{% if forms is defined %}
  {% for form in forms %}
    {% form_theme form 'form-front-end.html.twig' %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The good thing is that this would not throw any exceptions, even if you don't pass the variable at all, but you have to remember to put any forms to be rendered into the `forms` array.

Obviously, you would do the same thing for the back-end base template.

There may be better solutions, but in the meanwhile I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your very well written answer. So far, I found these solutions already, but I really was hoping someone had a better one. However, I fear this is the best possible currently :(

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem some times ago, found this post, and followed the way as Andrea Sprega suggested. Recently I came out of a way which can save some repetitive typings.

Warning: This is somewhat "hackish", is probably not the best way, and is not guarantee to work in next framework release. You'll see why when you read below.

Goal: We want to have different default form templates depending on the application "environment" (the most common examples would be "frontend" and "backend). But fundamentally Symfony isn't aware of such "environment". Although it is possible to split the project into different environments and load different configurations, this is definitely an overkill if what we want is just having different form templates.

I think the best way would be an ability to set/override the default form themes in the base template. So we can have form theme A in frontend base template, and form theme B in backend base template. This sounds the best solution to me because as form theme is a "view" stuff, it makes perfect sense to have it changed in the view. However, the problem seems to be that, when the twig (template) code is executed, the form view is already initialized. So it would be too late to change the default form theme there. (I could be wrong here, because I didn't dig deep enough to have 100% confidence)

So I decided to do it another way. It works like this:

- First, I made an assumption that all frontend controllers will extend the same base class (e.g. "BaseFrontendController"). Similarly, all backend controllers will extend the same BaseBackendController class. Here's how we distinguish a frontend and backend environment. This is actually the case in my project.
- The default twig templates will be added to these base controller classes. It can be done via a method, or an annotation. In this post I'll use a public method.
- Before the controller is executed, overwrite the defined default twig templates.
- When the form view is initialized, it will use the default twig template defined in the controller.

Here's how it's done:

Firstly, the default form themes defined in your `config.yml` will be passed to the constructor of `\Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractRendererEngine`, and is assigned to the local instance `$defaultThemes`. This field is protected so that it can be used by its derived classes, but there is no setter to change its value.

So, we need to roll our own `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine as BaseTwigRendererEngine;

class TwigRendererEngine extends BaseTwigRendererEngine
{
    /**
     * @param array $defaultThemes
     */
    public function addDefaultThemes($defaultThemes)
    {
        $this->defaultThemes = array_merge($this->defaultThemes, $defaultThemes);
    }
}
```

This custom renderer engine is plain simple - it just add a new method to append the default themes to the existing one. And this is why I say it's "hackish" - it will no longer work when the internal is changed.

Secondly, define an interface `TwigTemplateProvider` which is going to be implemented by the base frontend/backend controller classes:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Twig;

interface TwigTemplateProvider
{
    /**
     * @return array|string The form template path
     */
    public function getDefaultFormTwigTemplates();
}
```

Thirdly, we need a listener which will run when the controller is executed.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Form\Twig\TwigRendererEngine;
use AppBundle\Form\Twig\TwigTemplateProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class PerControllerFormTemplateListener
{
    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($controller[0] instanceof TwigTemplateProvider) {

            /** @var \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension $formExtension */
            $formExtension = $this->twig->getExtension('form');
            $engine = $formExtension->renderer->getEngine();
            if ($engine instanceof TwigRendererEngine) {
                $templates = (array)$controller[0]->getDefaultFormTwigTemplates();
                $engine->addDefaultThemes($templates);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The listener will get the form template name (in string or array) supplied by controllers implementing TwigTemplateProvider interface. Then it will add it to the default theme list and pass it to the form renderer engine.

Now, wire them together by adding the followings to your `services.yml`:

```
parameters:
    twig.form.engine.class: AppBundle\Form\Twig\TwigRendererEngine

services:
    app.form.per_controller_template_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\PerControllerFormTemplateListener
        arguments: ["@twig"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Here we set the `%twig.form.engine.class%` parameter to our own implementation, and added our event listener to the stack.

Using it is very simple. For example, in your base frontend controller, implement `TwigTemplateProvider` and add the following method:

```
public function getDefaultFormTwigTemplates()
{
    return 'frontend/form_layout.html.twig';
}
```

Then this layout will be added to the form template stack when your front controller is executed.